# Is there any significance to these fiery flowers in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

So I was strolling along my objectives late yesterday evening when I stumbled across some flowers that were on fire:

[image: Screenshot of the fiery flowers.]

When I arrived, the area immediately surrounding them was engulfed in flames. Unfortunately, they subsequently died down as I lined up a screenshot. I also checked the general area and there were no elemental enemies so I became highly curious...

---

What are these flowers, and do they have any significance in the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a resource known as [Flaming Flower Stamen](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Flaming_Flower_Stamen). There other similar flowers to it, such as the [Mist Flower Corolla](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Mist_Flower_Corolla). Once you harvest them, you can use the materials you obtain for crafting.

If you get too close, they will explode and radiate elemental damage according to its element. In order to harvest the Flaming Flower, you need to use either a Hydro or Cryo elemental attack to extinguish it (pyro for the Mist Flower)